# htaccess rewrite folder with category name and post url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo

I would like to be able to rewrite the url on my webpage so it also includes a category.

What I want is the URL to look something like this.

```
mypage.com/blog/category_name/post_url
```

What I have now is a folder called blog where I have an .htaccess file but I don't really understand how to use the variables to create something like above example. This is what I have right now.
my post details page is located inside blog folder.

My current url to access

```
mypage.com/blog/post_details.php?post_id=post_url&category_name=ABC
```

so the final url should look like

```
mypage.com/blog/ABC/post_url
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your URL after `mypage.com/blog`.

I assume your categories and IDs are composed with letters and digits, but you can adapt it if it is not the case.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

First, a serie of letter and digit, then a `/`, then an other serie of letter and digit.

The parentheses allow you to identify each group (`$1` and `$2`) in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*) post_details.php?post_id=$2&category=$1
```

Comment: Although I had already found the solution..Thanks . It works